# Flask, MySQL and SQLAlchemy querying ID error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I get a weird error when I try to query an item by id. I have tried all suggestion I have found and only when doing raw query I get a proper result.

Part of the Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_requ`est
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "xow.py", line 24, in get_user
    a = User.get_item(user_id)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\xo\xow\models\users.py", line 57, in get_item
    result = User.query.filter_by(id=idd).first()
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2659, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2457, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 86, in instances
    util.raise_from_cause(err)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 71, in instances
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 428, in _instance
    loaded_instance, populate_existing, populators)
  File "C:\Users\pgsid\Envs\xo\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 486, in _populate_full
    dict_[key] = getter(row)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

The query is `result = User.query.filter_by(id=idd).first()` with idd of type `int`.

The type of the ID field in MySQL db is `INT`

and the model is like this

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id          = db.Column('id', db.INT, primary_key=True)
    name        = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, index=True)
    post        = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, nullable=True)
    type        = db.Column(db.VARCHAR)
    url         = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, nullable=True)
    subtype     = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, nullable=True)
    tel         = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, nullable=True)
    address     = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, nullable=True)
    latitude    = db.Column(db.FLOAT)
    longitude   = db.Column(db.FLOAT)
    deleted     = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    children    = db.relationship("Children")
```

The database is initialized as such:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:test@localhost/mydb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

What could be wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that your full user model?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: @karin no I will post it all.

Comment: Sometimes this happens when your model has different types than those in the DB. Can you check the content of your DB for this row?

Comment: Are you sure that `idd` is an integer? Where does it come from?

Comment: @dirn yeah. comes from a route `@app.route('/user/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])`. Doing type(idd) comes up with int

Comment: That's `user_id`. What about `idd`?

Comment: @dirn same. Because it get's passed to the query. Even if I query by name I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the fact that in the MySQL schema for some reason deleted was defined as a `BIT` type.

All type combinations in SQLAlchemy failed. I had to change the schema to make it into a `TINYINT(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your id type as such:

```
id = db.Column('id', db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
```